# swift 3 - como fechar um ultimo popover aberto sobre outro popover ?

Tags: ios, swift, popover

Tenho uma viewcontroller que abre um popover. Este primeiro abre um segundo popover. Porém quando dou um self.dismiss em qualquer um dos popovers está fechando todos os popovers e a viewcontroller que o chamou.

Utilizo os seguintes comandos para chamar cada popover:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "callDriverPopupSegue", sender: self)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "callDriverPopSegue" {
    let popOver = segue.destination as! CallDriverPopup
    popOver.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popOver.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
   }
}
```

Para fechar uso:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução. Com as duas instruções abaixo eu consegui fechar o popover aberto.

```
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho a resposta para seu problema abaixo, o cenário é diferente mas a solução é  mesma. Você tem que escrever o codigo para fechar o popover no view controller atual. Escreve o seu código nos seu dismissVIew metodo do seu controler.

- var tmpController :UIViewController! = self.presentingViewController;

  ```
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
      println("done");
      tmpController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
  });*
  ```

Exemplo [aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4KnvB_2930aZmNBLUZITWlQQ0k/view)